# Convetir un string a un date

Tags: php

**quiero convertir '01102018' en '01-10-2018'** he intentado con date, pero no he tenido éxito, de antemano muchas gracias.

```
date`('d-m-y','01102018');`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estimado.

Para resolver su problema pruebe lo siguiente:

```
//crea la variable de tipo date desde la fecha de tipo texto del ejemplo
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY', "01102018");
//formatea la fecha para imprimirla con el formato deseado
$date = $date->format('d-m-Y');
//imprime la variable
echo $date;
```

Con eso deberia bastar.

Comment: revisa el formato que quiere de salida, tu código debería ser `d-m-Y`

Comment: Gracias hermano, funcionó de maravilla! Saludos.